# I need filtered values with index name from data

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting values what I have filtered from below script but not getting index name can help me to get with index name

chas = df.CHAS[df.CHAS>=1]

chas

for above script am getting result like below

142    1

152    1

154    1

155    1

I need result like below

```
CHAS
```

141 1

152 1

154 1

155 1

Comment: Show a small sample of the structure of df, for example by running df.head() which gives the top 5 rows, be sure to include the CHAS columnar value samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to obtain a DataFrame instead of a Series. Simple, just ask for a list of 1 column:

```
df[['CHAS']][df.CHAS >=1]
```

or even better:

```
df.loc[df['CHAS']>=1, [CHAS]]
```